# Python Full Screen Clock centered and with a label date and day of the week

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

Hello I'm doing a little program to do a full screen clock for my 3th monitor, I'm facing 2 troubles on my code because I'm not an expert on python.

**1st** I want to center my label, I'm facing some problems;

**2sd** I want just behind my clock, another label with date:

*Example :day/month/year - Day of Week ("Monday");*

```
from tkinter import *
import time 
window=Tk()
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window.title("CLS RELÓGIO")
window.grid_propagate(0)


l=Label(window,bg='BLACK',fg='white', font=('Árial',290,'bold'),bd=400)
l.grid(row=0,column=1)
def changetime():
    tm=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    l.config(text=tm)
    l.after(200,changetime)
changetime()
window.mainloop()
```

Can someone help me on this?

**I need help on facing these 2 little problems in python :**

https://prnt.sc/VFFHwbM5aPhs - just with my code

https://prnt.sc/Fv4IxQtMLWE7 - what I need

Answer (score 0):

Here is code.

Snippet:

```
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Digital Clock")
root.geometry("600x300")

def changetime():
    
    current_time = time.strftime("%H : %M : %S")     
    digital_clock.config(text=current_time)    
    digital_clock.after(200, changetime)

dt = datetime.now()

digital_clock = tk.Label(root,font=("times",60,"bold"),bg="blue", fg="white")
digital_clock.grid(row=0,column=2, pady=25, padx=100)

changetime()
 
day_of_week = tk.Label(root,text=f"Day of Week: {dt.strftime('%A')}", font="times 24 bold")
day_of_week.grid(row=2,column=2)
  
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]